# Normalize css e reset Global

Tags: css, html5, aplicação-web

Existe alguma forma de usar Normalize css e ao mesmo tempo dar um reset global nas folhas de estilo? Eu utilizo o reset assim no meu css:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Mas mesmo colocando o meu arquivo no link rel depois no normalize css ele não consegue sobrescrever. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso funcionar junto com normalize?

Comment: por que não da um !important?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `!important` para que ele não use a hierarquia do css.

O código vai depender de como ele foi carregado (A sequência de inclusão no HTML e por hierarquia).

Se por um exemplo você carregar este código depois de todos os outros CSS que tiver na página, ele vai sobrescrever o que estava anteriormente, ou caso queira priorizar alguma outra coisa, pode também colocando tags para deixar o código cada vez mais específico para o elemento e assim ele manter a formatação que você escolher.

Pode ver mais exemplos nesse link:

https://tableless.com.br/efeito-cascata-e-especificidade-do-css/